# HTTPS/SSL won't work on IE + Redirecting users to non-HTTPS based on Browser/OS on nginx

Tags: internet-explorer, redirect, ssl, nginx, https

I have set up SSL for my website using Comodo PositiveSSL on nginx (ubuntu 12.04, Rails4) and have redirects for http to https.

This works fine on most configurations that I tend to use (Firefox, Chrome etc) but I cannot be sure all users will be using one of these.

I've discovered that this will not work on many versions of IE. The SSL certificate is not recognized and you get the scary "website is unsafe" warning.

I've essentially followed the steps outline in this [github gist](https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/6487319).

1. Is there a way of overcoming this? I looked around and can't seem to find any solution.
2. What I next tried was to exclude IE in the http->https redirect. However, this is messing up Chrome which also gets redirected as if it were IE (on WinXP). This is the snippet in the server

   if ($http_user_agent !~ "MSIE") { 
       return 301 https://mywebsite.com$request_uri; 
   }

Full code [gisted here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9608336).

I've also tried the [browser module method](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpBrowserModule)

Can anyone recommend a good solution to the issue?

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO! Please do post code from the other solutions you have already tried, with details of what happened when you tried them,  and why they failed (did you get errors, did they do the same thing with the security certificate ETC..) to help us diagnose your problem and help you with a solution :)

Comment: Thanks. Well, the cert works on other browsers I've tried, it seems to be problematic only on IE and/or Windows XP. I don't get any other error other than the untrusted error message in the first case. In the case of the 2 redirect attempts, it just won't redirect as desired. When it works for IE, it also mistakes Chrome to be IE, and therefore redirecting Chrome as well, while I want Chrome to stay with https.